# How can I toggle the display of a textarea via a button using knockout with the foreach binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am new to knockout. For my problem, I am trying to make it so that for each project, there is a button and textarea. The textarea will be hidden upon page load. If I click the button, it will show the textarea (toggle). Currently, if I click the button, ALL textareas on the page will show, rather than just the corresponding textarea.

I'm hoping the fix for this isn't too dramatic and involving a complete reworking of my code as by some magic, every other functionality has been working thus far. I added the {attr id: guid} (guid is a unique identifier of a project retrieved from the database) statement in an attempt to establish a unique ID so that the right controls were triggered...although that did not work.

Sorry I do not have a working jfiddle to show the issue... I tried to create one but it does not demonstrate the issue.

JS:

```
 //if a cookie exists, extract the data and bind the page with cookie data
    if (getCookie('filterCookie')) {
        filterCookie = getCookie('filterCookie');
        var cookieArray = filterCookie.split(",");
        console.log(cookieArray);

        $(function () {
            var checkboxes = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < cookieArray.length; i++) {
                console.log(i + cookieArray[i]);
                checkboxes.push(getCheckboxByValue(cookieArray[i]));
                //checkboxes.push(document.querySelectorAll('input[value="' + cookieArray[i] + '"]'));
                console.log(checkboxes);
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        })

        filterCookie = getCookie('filterResultsCookie');
        cookieArray = filterCookie.split(",");
        filterCookieObj = {};
        filterCookieObj.action = "updateProjects";
        filterCookieObj.list = cookieArray;
        $.ajax("/api/project/", {
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(filterCookieObj)
        }).done(function (response) {


            proj = response;
            ko.cleanNode(c2[0]);
            c2.html(original);
            ko.applyBindings(new ProjectViewModel(proj), c2[0]);

        });
    }

//if the cookie doesn't exist, just bind the page
    else {
        $.ajax("/api/project/", {
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                action: "getProjects"
            })
        }).done(function (response) {
            proj = response;
            ko.cleanNode(c2[0]);
            c2.html(original);
            ko.applyBindings(new ProjectViewModel(proj), c2[0]);

        });
    }
```

View Model:

```
function ProjectViewModel(proj) {
            //console.log(proj);
            var self = this;
            self.projects = ko.observableArray(proj);
            self.show = ko.observable(false);
            self.toggleTextArea = function () {
                self.show(!self.show());
            };
        };
```

HTML:

```
                <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
            <div id="eachOppyProject" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/tools/oppy/' + guid }" style="font-size: 25px;"><span class="link" data-bind="    value: guid, text: name"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-bind="text: projectDescription"></tr>
<%--                    <tr data-bind="text: guid"></tr>--%>
                </tbody>
            </table>
                 <span class="forminputtitle">Have you done project this before?</span>  <input type="button" value="Yes" data-bind="click: $parent.toggleTextArea" class="btnOppy"/>
                <textarea placeholder="Tell us a little of what you've done." data-bind="visible: $parent.show, attr: {'id': guid }" class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" style="height:75px; " /><br />
                <span> <input type="checkbox" name="oppyDoProjectAgain" style="padding-top:10px; padding-right:20px;">I'm thinking about doing this again. </span>
            <br />
                </div><br />
                <!-- /ko -->
```

Spencer:

```
function ProjectViewModel(proj) {
    //console.log(proj);
    var self = this;
    self.projects = ko.observableArray(proj);
    self.projects().forEach(function() { //also tried proj.forEach(function())
        self.projects().showComments = ko.observable(false);
        self.projects().toggleComments = function () {
            self.showComments(!self.showComments());
        };
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird that

```
data-bind="visible: show"
```

doesn't provide any binding error because context of binding inside ko foreach: project is project not the ProjectViewModel.

Anyway, this solution should solve your problem:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var wrappedProjects = proj.map(function(p) {
        return new Project(p);
    });
    self.projects = ko.observableArray(wrappedProjects);
}

function Project(proj) {
   var self = proj;   
   self.show = ko.observable(false);
   self.toggleTextArea = function () {
       self.show(!self.show());
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I pass `proj` to `self.projects = ko.observableArray(proj);`? Currently, `proj` is the JSON that is returned from the server that contains the data that needs to be displayed. And where does `function Project(proj)` get called?

Comment: @SKY, Ok, so my idea was to wrap each`proj` element using `new Project(proj)`, so each one has it's own `show()` and `toggleTextArea` properties.

Comment: I see, so when does `new Project(proj)` actually get called?

Comment: I tried your solution, and I assume I would have to update the bindings in html, right? It wouldn't simply be `data-bind="text: projectDescription"` anymore since there's a mapping, right? Would it be something like `projects().wrappedProjects.projectDescription`? Or something like `<!-- ko foreach: projects().wrappedProjects -->`? (I tried these statements already)

Comment: No, `wrappedProjects` is a result array that is put to fill `projects` observable array, binding doesn't change, still use `<!-- ko foreach: projects -->. You need to change bindings `data-bind="visible: $parent.show"` to `data-bind="visible: show"` and 'data-bind=click: $parent.toggleTextArea"` to `data-bind="click: toggleTextArea"` (since now each projects' item has it's own set of `show` and `toggleTextArea` properties)

Comment: Okay, the reason why I ask because now, it's no longer seeing certain attributes in `proj`. `data-bind="Text: projectDescription` now returns an `Unable to process binding` error after including your code, so I figured it was because of the wrapping. Do you have any idea why it's now not able to access the properties of `proj`?

Comment: @SKY, my bad, `return self;` was missing in Project(). See http://jsfiddle.net/ek1tvnhd/ for working solution.

Comment: I have posted another question. In case you are interested in answering... it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118901/how-to-obtain-input-from-multiple-textareas-on-the-click-of-a-button-using-knock

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `show` observable needs to be defined in the projects array. Currently all the textareas are looking at the same observable. This means you'll have to move the function `showTextArea` into the projects array as well.

Also you may want to consider renaming your function or getting rid of it entirely. Function names which imply they drive a change directly to the view fly in the face of the MVVM pattern. I'd recommend a name like "toggleComments" as it doesn't reference a view control.

EDIT:

As an example:

```
function ProjectViewModel(proj) {
    //console.log(proj);
    var self = this;
    self.projects = ko.observableArray(proj);
    foreach(var project in self.projects()) {
        project.showComments = ko.observable(false);
        project.toggleComments = function () {
            self.showComments(!self.showComments());
        };
    }
};
```

There is probably a much cleaner way to implement this in your project I just wanted to demonstrate my meaning without making a ton of changes to the code you provided.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `This means you'll have to move the function showTextArea into the projects array as well.` ?

Comment: Report I added your solution with some fixes to your syntax (see my edited post with your name above it) There were various issues -- I played with the syntax and none of it worked. The click event does nothing. Do you have any ideas? Thank you for assisting me, I hope we are able to come to a solution!