# How to obtain input from multiple textareas and radio buttons on the click of a button using knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, textarea

I have several textareas and radio buttons that are dynamically generated inside a `ko: foreach` binding. When a user decides they are done typing their input, they will click a button 'OK' which takes all of the input of the textareas and values of the radio buttons they have chosen and it should trigger an ajax call to the server because the input needs to be stored in a database. Each textarea and radiobutton value is stored separately, so they need to be sent to the server as distinguished values. I've been having a lot of trouble given the `foreach` binding, so I'm not sure where to begin because the textareas do not have an accessible unique identifier because they're generated using `foreach`. Thank you.

So, in simpler terms:

1. User types in multiple textareas and clicks on radio buttons.
2. User clicks 'OK' button when finished typing. Button click function retrieves user input in all textareas and radio button values.
3. Trigger ajax call and send values to server.

Any help is appreciated or links to any resources that I can follow. My google searches didn't quite answer my questions.

Picture:
[image]

Server:

```
//retrieves form data from the client and serialized it
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {            
            // get json out of body
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
            var jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr);
            dynamic data = serializer.Deserialize(jtr);

            if (data.action == "getProjects")
            {
                getProjects(data);
            }

        }
```

Example Object that is posted via ajax:

```
    Obj = {};
    Obj.action = "getProjects";
    Obj.list = arrayOfCheckboxValues;
```

View:

```
        <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
        <div id="eachOppyProject">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/tools/oppy/' + guid }"><span class="link" data-bind="value: guid, text: name"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr data-bind="text: projectDescription"></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="visible: firstAnswers, click: function () { showBtnOK(); showDoneTA(); }">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" />
                    Did it already
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="visible: firstAnswers, click: function () { showInterestedTA(); showBtnOK(); }">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" />Didn't do it, but interested</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="visible: firstAnswers, click: function () { neverInterested(); showBtnOK(); }">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" />Never done it; not interested</label>
            </div>

            <div data-bind="visible: doneAnswer">
                <textarea placeholder="Tell us a little of what you've done. Like, when did you do it? Who was in charge of it? Things like that."
                    class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="textInput: doneProject, attr: { id: guid, name: guid + 'doneProject' }"
                    />
                <textarea placeholder="If there's anything else you'd like us to know, tell us here."
                    class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="textInput: doneProjectComment, attr: { id: guid, name: guid + 'doneProjectComment' }"/>
            </div>

            <div data-bind="visible: interestedAnswer">
                <textarea placeholder="So, you're interested, huh? Tell us why."
                    class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="attr: { id: guid, name: guid + 'interestedProject' }"/>
                <textarea placeholder="If there's anything else you'd like us to know, tell us here."
                    class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="attr: { id: guid, name: guid + 'interestedProjectComment' }"/>
            </div>


            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="visible: doneAnswer, click: function () { showBtnOK(); showInterestedMoreTA(); }">

                    <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" />
                    Interested in doing more</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default" data-bind="visible: doneAnswer, click: function () { showBtnOK(); notInterestedMore(); }">

                    <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" />
                    No plans to do this again</label>
            </div>

            <div data-bind="visible: interestedMore">
                <textarea placeholder="You want to do more? Way to go! Tell us more!"
                    class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="attr: { id: guid, name: guid + 'interestedMore' }, value: $parent.saved_value"/>
                <textarea placeholder="If there's anything else you'd like us to know, tell us here."
                    class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="attr: { id: guid, name: guid + 'interestedMoreComment' }"/>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: right;">

            <input type="button" data-bind="visible: btnOK, click: function () { clearView(); }" value="OK" class="btn btn-default "/><br /><br />
        </div> //this is the button that captures all input

        </div>


        <!-- /ko -->
```

View Model:

```
function ViewModel(proj) {
    var self = this;
    var wrappedProjects = proj.map(function (p) {
        return new Project(p);
    });
    self.projects = ko.observableArray(wrappedProjects);
}


function Project(proj) {
    var self = proj;
    self.firstAnswers = ko.observable(true);
    self.doneAnswer = ko.observable(false);
    self.showDoneTA = function () {
        self.doneAnswer(true);
        self.interestedAnswer(false);
    }
    self.interestedAnswer = ko.observable(false);
    self.showInterestedTA = function () {
        self.interestedAnswer(true);
        self.doneAnswer(false);
        self.interestedMore(false);
    }
    self.interestedMore = ko.observable(false);
    self.showInterestedMoreTA = function () {
        self.interestedMore(true);
    }
    self.notInterestedMore = function () {
        self.interestedMore(false);
    }
    self.neverInterested = function () {
        self.doneAnswer(false);
        self.interestedAnswer(false);
        self.interestedMore(false);
    }
    self.btnOK = ko.observable(false);
    self.showBtnOK = function () {
        self.btnOK(true);
        console.log(self.btnOK());
    }
    self.savedMSG = ko.observable(false);
    self.clearView = function () {
        self.firstAnswers(false);
        self.doneAnswer(false);
        self.interestedAnswer(false);
        self.interestedMore(false);
        self.btnOK(false);
        self.savedMSG(true);
    }
    self.showFirstAnswers = function () {
        self.firstAnswers(true);
        self.savedMSG(false);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generating the textareas in a foreach is not a problem and they don't need unique identifiers.

I am not sure what:

```
var wrappedProjects = proj.map(function (p) {
        return new Project(p);
    });
```

does but assuming it generates an array of Projects, the foreach is fine.
I did notice not all of your textareas have value bindings which would cause them not to be populated with values.

I did see this binding:$parent.saved_value. In this case $parent would be ViewModel and that is not defined.

I was getting errors with the foreach until I changed the:

```
<textarea/>
```

to:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

knockout was throwing an error stating the foreach was not closed.

I suspect you are approaching this from a "jQuery mindset", because you do things like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="textInput: doneProjectComment, attr: { id: guid, name: guid + 'doneProjectComment' }"/>
```

It looks to me like you're try to set unique IDs and names, in the hope of reading the val() of the input with jQuery when it's time to submit. While I don't know what your `textInput` binding is, it seems that `doneProjectComment` is not an observable on your `Project` data model, and thus the data entered in that `<textarea>` doesn't really end up anywhere.

The Knockout way is to add a `doneProjectComment` observable on your `Project`, and bind to it with the `value` binding:

```
<textarea class="form-control newSessionAnalyst" data-bind="value: doneProjectComment"/>

function Project(proj) {
  self.doneProjectComment = ko.observable();
}
```

Knockout gives you two-way bindings. In case of the `value: doneProjectComment` binding, this means that if the user types into the textarea, the value is saved into `doneProjectComment`. If `doneProjectComment` is changed, the new value is shown in the textarea.

So if you want to gather all the data when the user clicks 'ok', you can do it easily from inside the `Project` - just read all the observables you care about, and create a hash that `jQuery.post` can user as AJAX parameters:

```
function Project(proj) {
  self.toAjaxParameters = function(){
    return {
      interested: self.interestedAnswer(),
      done: self.doneAnswer(),
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

html:

If you setup a `save` function on your ViewModel

```
self.save = function(project){
  $.post('/url-to-post-to', project.toAjaxParameters());
}
```

html:

```
<button data-bind="click:$parent.save"></button>
```

I would suggest installing [Knockout Context Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en) it makes debugging knockout problems a lot easier.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your thorough comment!! The `proj.map` was a solution I followed to hide/show textareas and other controls. I have updated my post to include a picture to show you a project with some controls displayed, while the projects below it have hidden controls.

How would you grab values from `self` that is `Project`? Also, is it possible to trigger ajax calls inside the function? Because I have to send the data that is captured to the server. 

Otherwise, I think I understand your suggestion and thank you!

Comment: @SKY GrayTower is right - create a `save` function on the view model, and let the `project` data model do the data gathering. @GrayTower I'll expand your answer instead of writing a new one - hope that's okay.

Comment: @janfoeh Thank you. Where you have `&.post('url')`, how can I specify the action? I'm currently not posting directly to a method, i.e.: url/method. I specify a object.action = 'methodName' because I am posting form data. I've updated my post to show you what happens on the server.

Comment: Also for `self.save = function(project){
  $.post('/url-to-post-to', project.toAjaxParameters());
}` is `project` the same `proj` that is currently being passed to the View Model in my post? Because I keep getting some undefined errors when it gets to this save function. Trying to test different ways of writing it.

Comment: @SKY I am not sure what you mean by "object.action", but I suspect that you're talking about your backend implementation of a form builder. I cannot help you there, but from the view of the frontend, it's just URLs — you'll have to figure out which URL it is. `$.post` posts form data just as well - only via AJAX. You don't need a `<form>` element for that. The `project` parameter in the view models `save` function comes from the `click:$parent.save` binding. `click` passes the current `$data` scope to `$parent.save`, so you get the current project in `$data` as set by `ko foreach: projects`.

Comment: @SKY `<form action="/my-url">` is equal to an jQuery AJAX call of `$.post('/my-url')`. Both define a URL to which an HTTP POST request will be made. The difference is in how the data is defined that will be sent alongside the POST request. Whereas in HTML you would define, say, `<input type="text" name="myvalue1"><input type="text" name="myvalue2">`, for an AJAX POST request you simply pass the values as an object hash: `$.post('/my-url', {myvalue1: 'a', myvalue2: 'b'})`.

Comment: I see, I am attempting to test if I can retrieve the data with `self.save = function (project) {
            console.log(project.doneProject);` or with `console.log(project);` but it is returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'doneProject' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69566/discussion-between-sky-and-janfoeh).

Comment: Looking at the models doneProject is not defined anywhere neither is doneProjectComment